# Getting an error when trying to insert data into SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I am using the following code to update a "Picture" field in my SQLite database:

```
    public void SetImage(byte[] image)
    {
        var sql = "UPDATE Part SET Picture=@0 WHERE PartId=" + PartId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var con = new SQLiteConnection(GetConnectionString());

        var command = new SQLiteCommand(con)
        {
            CommandText = sql
        };

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@0", image);
        con.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        command.Dispose();
        con.Dispose();
    }
```

All other data access to and from my SQLite database works fine. It just seems that when I try to insert data into this one field, it gives me an error "Database is locked". My application is single threaded and all of my other data access functions properly close and dispose of the proper objects. Anyone have a clue what might be wrong?

Comment: have u opened db from some client manager at the same time?

Comment: @nawfal - No. I closed it and I even closed my virus scanner and anything else that might be opening the file up.

Comment: @icemsnind. I have had the same issue several times and mostly when I update my ado.net sqlite connector. certain versions work without any fuss while certain other not - not necessarily older version. even newer versions gives me this trouble when older version ran fine. The only solution that worked for me was disposing the SQLite objects using the using block as CL suggests. I would better ask you to incorporate a helper class that manages this so that you dont have the hassle of using `using` and freeing resources everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error "Database is locked" is likely to indicates that some other connection still has an open transaction.

Ensure that *all* commands and connections are properly closed and disposed.
To do that even in the case of exceptions, use `using`.

Comment: I have so thoroughly looked through my code and I simply can not find any place where connections and commands aren't being closed. I will admit that I am calling `Dispose()` on the objects rather then using `using` blocks, but that shouldn't matter, right? Also, I used [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to try to figure out what is going on. I've stepped through my code and locks on the database are always successful up to the `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` line. Then it just fails...Its almost like SQLite is exclusively locking itself from the DB

Comment: You can jump out of code with things like `break`, `return`, or exceptions. Therefore, you should *always* use `using` blocks.

Comment: I am at work now, but when I get home, I will change everything to `using` blocks and I will report my findings.

Comment: Still the same issue, but I have noticed something. When I run the program on my computer, it fails, however, when I run it on a friend's computer, it seems to work. The difference between our machines is that my computer is a quad core processor and his is a single core processor (Though he does have hyperthreading). Is it possible that SQLite is doing something to the database in one core while its doing something else in another core? I know my program is not multithreaded. Any clues?

Comment: @icemanind are you so sure that every single query from your application to db involves a `using` or `Dispose`? Try with `using` then.

Comment: @nawfal - I even single stepped through my application line by line till I got to the offending update line. I can verify that Dispose() is getting called. I will try 'using' just to see. Perhaps an internal error in the SQLite DLL file is causing an exception and perhaps using might fix it

Comment: @nawfal - Wow it is working once I rebuilt the entire data layer using 'using' blocks. I was absolutely 100% disposing each object, so its a puzzler to me why 'using' makes a difference, but it seems to work now! Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @icemanind good to know. As I said wrap the entire `using` and repetitive db code to one helper class. If you had done once, the matter of now changing `Dispose` to `using` would have been a matter of editing one line :)